# How do I use a custom bit.ly URL in a tweet, rather than t.co?

Tags: javascript, twitter, bit.ly

I've setup bit.ly to use a custom URL. Works perfect if I paste a link into bit.ly, it outputs the custom URL, so I know that piece is setup.

The main question is this: How do I setup the "Tweet" button on my site so that when a user clicks "Tweet" the URL that appears in the tweet is shortened with our custom URL rather than Twitters t.co URL?

Thanks!

**MORE INFORMATION:**

Just to give a better example:
http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/12/16/the-times-and-bitly-roll-out-nytims-short-links/

Scroll down to the end of the post and click the "Twitter" button, you'll see they are using their http://nyti.ms (http://nyti.ms/NUHtlN) which uses bit.ly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"All URLs regardless of their length are now automatically wrapped with t.co"**

Official Source:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2806

**EDIT:** Demonstration follows:

Going [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/29/us/tropical-storm-isaac-on-verge-of-becoming-a-category-1-hurricane.html?hp), and click the Twitter share button pops up a share box, populated with:

```
Isaac Upgraded to Category 1 Hurricane http://nyti.ms/RUs5HF
```

When this is [posted](https://twitter.com/joshoneal45/status/240551881720623104) to Twitter, it appears that Twitter creates a new wrapped hyperlink, in the form of:

```
<a href="http://t.co/wToOFYQc">http://nyti.ms/RUs5HF</a>
```

The Twitter post then has the appearance of using the `nyti.ms` link, but in actuality, it's just a `t.co` link.

Comment: A good example of this behavior is: http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/12/16/the-times-and-bitly-roll-out-nytims-short-links/

Scroll down to the end of the post and click the "Twitter" button, you'll see they are using their http://nyti.ms (http://nyti.ms/NUHtlN) which uses bitly...

Comment: @JasonVendryes: That article is from 2009. You can see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1062) that t.co wasn't initially required. However, in my post, from the people who wrote Twitter, from less than a year ago, you can now see that t.co is going to be the end result, whether you like it or not.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, however in an effort to make sure this is the final answer... This article on New York Times was posted 14 minutes ago, http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/29/us/tropical-storm-isaac-on-verge-of-becoming-a-category-1-hurricane.html?hp , same result if you click on the Twitter button, you get "Isaac Upgraded to Category 1 Hurricane http://nyti.ms/RUs5HF". Thoughts on that?